# Removing attribute on click with query

Tags: jquery, click

I'm having issues. I need this p tag to display whenever the a tag is clicked. These tags relate to a listing of news/blog posts so I need a jquery function that will work universally, regardless of the class listed with each post.

Here's a sample html snippet from part of a blog post.

```
<p style="display:none;" class="_83214">text goes here </p>
<a class="_83214" href="#">Read More</a>
```

Here's the jquery. I've done a similar thing for the navigation and it worked great, so I can't figure out why it isn't working now.

```
$('a').click(function() {
var myClass = this.className;
$("p." + myClass).css('display', 'initial');
});
```

**EDIT:** 
I got it to work! I placed the suggestion posted using the .prev method within the original JSON parsing code, instead of outside of it. Now it works like a charm and I don't have to use the classes.

Here's the final working code.

```
<script>

$.getJSON("js/news.json", function(data) {
    $.each(data.posts, function(index, val) {
        var title = val.title;
        var date = val.date;
        var content = val.content;
        var after = content.substring(300);
        if (content.length > 300) {
            content = content.substring(0, 300);
            $("#newscontainer").append('<div><h1>' + title + '</h1><h2>' + date + '</h2><p>' + content + '. . . </p> <p style="display: none;">' + after + '</p><a class="reveal" href="#">Read More</a></div><hr>');
            $('a.reveal').click(function() {
            $(this).prev().css('display', 'initial')});
        } else {
            $("#newscontainer").append('<div><h1>' + title + '</h1><h2>' + date + '</h2><p>' + content + '</p></div><hr>');
        }

    });
});


</script>
<div id='newscontainer'>
</div>
```

Comment: use display block instead...

Comment: If my answer using .prev() solved your problem, you should consider marking it as the accepted answer and/or upvoting it.

Comment: I need 15 reputation before I can up vote it. I did make it the accepted answer. Sorry if I offended you, I'm new to this site =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a class independent solution, use:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $(this).prev('p').css('display', 'initial');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('a').click(function() {
var myClass = $(this).attr("class");
$("p." + myClass).css('display', 'initial');
});
```

**EDIT**

Can u modified created html from json as u say like this

```
<p style="display:none;" class="_83214">text goes here </p>
<a onclick="javascript:displayPost($(this));return false;" class="_83214">Read More</a>
```

Javascript like this

```
function displayPost(anchor) {
    var myClass = anchor.attr("class");
    $("p." + myClass).css('display', 'initial');
});
```

Comment: That's what I originally had and it still isn't working as I'd hoped. Could it be because the html blog posts are being created and inserted by javascript and JSON?